# Java float array gives me multiple copies of same result

Tags: java, arrays, object, floating-point

```
public class SelectionEngine {
    int[] fitness;
    int percentage;
    float[] fortunePercentage;

    SelectionEngine(int[] fitnessArray){
        this.fitness=fitnessArray;

    }

   float[] createFortuneWheel(){

 [...]
        fortunePercentage = new float[this.fitness.length];
        for(int i=0;i<fitness.length;i++){
            perc= (float) this.fitness[i]/maxVal;
           sigma += 1-(perc);
        }

//now we load fortunePercentage table with percentages
       for(int i=0;i<this.fitness.length;i++) {
           perc= (float) (this.fitness[i]/maxVal);
           fortunePercentage[i]=((1-perc)/sigma);
       }

       return fortunePercentage;

    }
}
```

after i invoke this code in my main class, and want to assign fortunePercentage to an array, like this:

```
float[] fortuneTest =new float[fitnessTable.length];
    SelectionEngine selector = new SelectionEngine(fitnessTable);
    fortuneTest=selector.createFortuneWheel();
```

I get array that is full of SAME results, except for one zero, that has to happen because of math. my fitness[] table is full of different results, that are integers, and fortunePercentage should contain a table with percentages for each correcponding fitness value, and for worst one (longest) it should automatically evaluate to zero.

Instead, i get my fortuneTest array that is full of same results, AND one zero (or two, or three, if i got three equal worst values in my fitness table). Why?
Do arrays work differently in java than in c++?

Comment: `this.fitness[i]/maxVal;` if `maxVal` is an `int`, you get integer division here. Cast one to `float`.

Comment: `perc= (float) (this.fitness[i]/maxVal);`
so, i didnt cast the type correctly?

Comment: can you post the contents?

Comment: The first time you do it right: `perc= (float) this.fitness[i]/maxVal;` but the second time is incorrect: `perc= (float) (this.fitness[i]/maxVal);`

Comment: float(5/5) = 1.0 So Johhny's point is correct. You are casting float after division. Division's result is already integer and your casting add point zero (.0) to result

Comment: Ohhhh, thank you. It helped. Im new to java and i didnt know that i have to cast one of values before division.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of this:

```
perc= (float) this.fitness[i]/maxVal;
```

Try this:

```
perc= (float) (this.fitness[i]/maxVal);
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like its the other way around. In your second line you're casting integer division, whose result is invalid, to float. 
In first one you invoke floating-point division. I think.